# would not vs will not vs can not

Tags: word-usage, conditionals

I understand about the conditional, and imaginary, tense but if someone implies something will or won't work, which is the stronger or more definite use?

> 1. Even if he tries, it cannot work
> 2. Even if he tried, it would not work
> 3. Even if he tried, it will not work

Thank you. Sorry I wasn't more clear.

I was curious about the level of intention expressed in language, for a hypothetical situation - ie, whether will, would or could denotes that a person is more likely to do something, in this case try. Saying it would/wouldn't, seems to remove it that bit further from it taking place. I think Barrie has answered what I was trying to find out, ie intention as expressed in language.

eg 
1. It could not work (something will prevent it being successful)
2. It will not work (I might try, but probably unsuccessfully)
3. It would not work (I'm unlikely to try and even if I did, it will probably be unsuccessful)

Just curious about this subtle difference in the use of language on a psychological level.

Comment: No, that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Of the three, I find only one acceptable.

*Would* is usable in two modes

- to denote historical past
- to denote a propositional situation.

It is said that the English language has three tenses. That it has three temporal/time periods.

- past time
- present time
- future time

There is yet one more time period called the hypothetical time. It is often correlated to the subjunctive mode/mood. But the English language does not assign subjunctive/hypothetical time its own tense. The hypothetical time borrows its tenses from the past tenses, which often is the cause of the confusion.

Past time:

- Last year, he would come home straight from school.
- While on vacation last month, she could see Alaska from Russia.
- Yesterday, they had to go to work.

Hypothetical time:

- Even if it rains, he would come home straight from school.
- If she took a vacation to Nome, I am sure she could see Russia from Alaska.
- Had the boss called yesterday, they would have to go to work.

Therefore, whenever you encounter the need to use *would*, *could* or similar past-time words, you need to first decide if you are speaking of hypothetical time or real past-time.

We could also call hypothetical time, imaginary time. In hypothetical/imaginary time, you also have the past, present, future time, as well as infinite, progressive and perfected time ranges. I would love to give you examples of past, present, future, progressive or perfected imaginary actions, but that would be out of the scope of this  question.

Therefore, the following is obviously imaginary present:

> Even if he tried

which requires

> it would not work.

I wish to further advise you of another confusion because people frequently ask, why do you use *could* rather than *can*:

> Could you take your shoes off?

This is a form of politeness, where the requester deliberately uses imaginary time. By doing so, the requester is saying that

> I have a proposal for you. The proposal requests you to remove your shoes.

Where a proposal is an imaginary and non-fulfilling situation.

The following would be relatively rude, or imperative, if used among people familiar with propositional imaginary mode:

> Can you take your shoes off?

Answer (score 0):

(1) admits the possibility that he will try, but claims that even if he does the effort will be fruitless. (2) is equally pessimistic about the result, but casts greater doubt on the possibility of his trying. (3) is unlikely to be used at all, to the extent that it is probably ungrammatical.